# ambiguous column name: error not working with tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, ambiguous

I have some code to display my recipes in order of their popularity  as shown below. This is stored in my index file for the recipe view.

```
<% @all_recipes.this_week.reorder("likes_count DESC").limit(10).each do |i| %>
  <%=link_to image_tag(i.image(:fixed), alt: "MUC", :class => "browse-recipes"), i %>
<% end %>
```

As you can see I have passed a method 'this_week' which works perfectly defined as a scope.

My issue is, I have a tag cloud on the same page and when I click on a tag is should refresh the page but showing only those recipes with the associated tag.This works perfectly WITHOUT the this_week method applied but if the method is there I get the following error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: created_at: SELECT  "recipes".* FROM     "recipes" JOIN taggings recipes_taggings_81e277c  ON recipes_taggings_81e277c.taggable_id = recipes.id AND recipes_taggings_81e277c.taggable_type = 'Recipe' AND recipes_taggings_81e277c.tag_id = 33 WHERE "recipes"."live" = 't' AND (created_at > '2014-01-13 00:00:00.000000')  ORDER BY likes_count DESC LIMIT 10
```

Any thoughts? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You must have a `created_at` field in both the recipes and tags tables.  MySQL doesn't know which one it should order by.  Where ever you are doing the ordering (in the this_week scope or in the tag  method) you need to change this:

```
order('created_at')
```

to this:

```
order('recipes.created_at')
```

Assuming you want to order by the recipe's field.  And if you don't like hardcoding the table name you can use `self.class.table_name` and substitute that in.

Comment: Genius! Thanks this is just what I needed. It was annoyingly hidden away in one of my concerns!

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom can this be done with a hash and not a string?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon No. The hash version is only for asc/dec ala `order(created_at: desc)`

Comment: You can also do with `order('created_at').references(:recipes)`

Comment: I personally used `order("#{self.table_name}.created_at")` (without the `class`) and it worked for me